# VScode messes JSX format (beautify)

Tags: javascript, reactjs, visual-studio-code

I have this plugin installed: https://github.com/HookyQR/VSCodeBeautify

This is code I have

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';

export default class TempInput extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <div>
                <input
          value={temperature}
          onChange={this.handleChange} />


      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

After clicking Ctrl+Shift+I, first I get message that

> Could not determine type to beautify please choose.

Then it allows me to choose from HTML, JS, CSS. When I choose JS, this is result I get:

```
import React, {
  Component
} from 'react';

export default class TempInput extends Component {
  render() {
    return ( <
      div >
      <
      input value = {
        temperature
      }
      onChange = {
        this.handleChange
      }
      />


      <
      /div>
    );
  }
}
```

Any idea why?
Language mode is set as JS/React in VScode.

---

If I uninstall that plugin and click Ctrl+Shift+I, I get this error

> command 'HookyQR.beautifyFile' not found

Answer (score 23, accepted):

You don't need to use plugin for that: *`Change Language Mode`* command (<kbd>Ctrl + K</kbd><kbd>M</kbd>) offers **`JavaScript React`** option, what is basically JS with JSX support.

**Native** *`Format Document`* command (usually bound to <kbd>Alt + Shift + F</kbd>) then does the trick.

Comment: ctrl+shift+i was giving me that error message when uninstalled that plugin, this seems to work.

Comment: Yes, it can happen: uninstalled plugins leaves its settings in user config, from time to time it is even useful. Invoke `Open Keyboard Shorcuts` and look for unneeded `extension.` ones.

Answer (score 0):

Use a beautify tool that explicitly supports JSX such as [react-beautify](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=taichi.react-beautify) or [prettier](https://github.com/prettier/prettier-vscode).

VSCodeBeautify may support JSX however seems to be cases where it does not work. See [GitHub Issue 132](https://github.com/HookyQR/VSCodeBeautify/issues/132).

Comment: i'll check prettier, first seems to be out of market.

Comment: we're using prettier in our project - works like a charm